# Rewriting old WordPress urls to new site's URL structure via .htaccess

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Hey folks, I've migrated a site from WordPress to a new CMS, and I want to preserve the old URLs via a redirect.

The WordPress permalink structure was like so:

`/2011/04/01/name-of-post`

I've preserved the post slugs, so all I need to do is get rid of the date-based paths and redirect to my new directory structure:

`/articles/view/name-of-post`

My attempts thus far have looked like this (in my .htaccess file):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/(.+)$ /articles/view/$1 [L]
```

No luck yet. I tried `%{PATH_INFO}` in there as well, no dice.

Any help from those more versed in Apache rewrite rules than would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do.

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/20../../../(.*)$           /articles/view/$1
```

Comment: That did it, thanks. For posterity: `RedirectMatch ^/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/(.+)$ /articles/view/$1 [L,R=301]`

Answer (score 0):

It can be handled in one simple RewriteRule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/(.+)$ /articles/view/$1 [L]
```